# Missing DNA Block while rendering through commandline rendering on google colab

Tags: rendering

I have been rendering a project on google Colab Pro using the TPUs and high RAM with this script: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q_ufEUtv9DYNGA_n3Ai3sgN6k6g_tfhh/view?usp=sharing

It had been working very well for a few iterations and recently I started getting a "missing DNA block" error. I looked into this a lot before posting and it seems like when other folks get this error the file is somehow corrupted and usually it's best to just use the backup files etc. The strange thing is that I'm able to open the files on my computer with no errors, I've only gotten the errors once it's on google drive and rendering through Colab services. I've also tried rendering older files I know had worked before and those are now also getting this error so I'm thinking it's something on the Colab side rather than in blender.

Thanks for any help or ideas you can offer!

Comment: Hello and welcome :) Your file is locked, unless your script it is too long to paste here please [edit] and leave relevant bit in the body of the question so that users can see without needing follow links. Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that. I just updated it.